# Java to implement TransformationDictionary PMML model

Tags: java, pmml

I know there is `jpmml`, but it seems the `jpmml` only supports `evaluator` part from `PMML`.

I have a PMML model file exported from *KNIME* *Category to Number* node, and I need it in Java. some of its content like below shown:

```
  <TransformationDictionary>
    <DerivedField displayName="LIVE_STS" name="LIVE_STS*" optype="continuous" dataType="integer">
      <Extension name="summary" extender="KNIME" value="Generated by KNIME - Category2Number node"/>
        <MapValues outputColumn="out" dataType="integer">
          <FieldColumnPair field="LIVE_STS" column="in"/>
          <InlineTable>
            <row>
              <pmml:in>N</pmml:in>
              <pmml:out>0</pmml:out>
            </row>
            <row>
              <pmml:in>L</pmml:in>
              <pmml:out>1</pmml:out>
            </row>
          </InlineTable>
        </MapValues>
      </DerivedField>
```

Above is only a part of it.

Any package in java can implement the logic? or if `jpmml` could do, which package should I use please?

Comment: Discussed here: https://github.com/jpmml/jpmml-evaluator/issues/46

Answer (score 1):

I already asked the member of *jpmml* as issue in github.

check out this link:

[the_link](https://github.com/jpmml/jpmml-evaluator/issues/46)

it gave an alternative for this issue, which solved the problem in another way.